# GCD of two polynomials in Mod 2

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1)

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes.

I wonder is the following statement always true?
$$\gcd(x^p-1, x^q-1) \stackrel{?}{=} x-1$$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, we have $\gcd(x^n-1,x^m-1)=x^{\gcd(n,m)}-1$.

Comment: I have just found http://www2.hawaii.edu/~robertop/Courses/Math_454/Handouts/HW_Nov_30_sols.pdf Do you know a proof?

Comment: @user706071 Strong induction works, since for $n\geq m$, $\gcd(x^n-1, x^m-1) = \gcd(x^n-x^m, x^m-1) = \gcd(x^{n-m} -1, x^m-1)$